# Problems aligning buttons in widget in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qabstractbutton

I've been trying to create a widget with image background and two buttons (cancel and ok) with image and push down/up effect, using pyqt5 GUI of python language, but I have two problem:

1 – I can't align the buttons in widget center

2 – The buttons events occur twice

Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class PicButton(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, pixmap_pressed, id_button, parent=None):
        super(PicButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.pixmap_pressed = pixmap_pressed
        self.id_buton = id_button

        self.pressed.connect(self.update)
        self.released.connect(self.update)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.isDown():
            pix = self.pixmap_pressed
            print("botao pressionado: ", self.id_buton)
        else:
            pix = self.pixmap

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), pix)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.update()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(131, 82)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setGeometry(800, 450, 800, 450)

pixmap = QPixmap("background.png")
brush = QBrush(pixmap)
palette = QPalette()
palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background, brush)
window.setPalette(palette)

button1 = PicButton(QtGui.QPixmap("cancel_up.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("cancel_down.png"), "cancel")
button2 = PicButton(QtGui.QPixmap("ok_up.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("ok_down.png"), "ok")

layout = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addStretch(1)
layout.addWidget(button1)
layout.addWidget(button2)
layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Get images in link: https://www.filedropper.com/imagens

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I can't align the buttons in widget center**: If you have applied `addStretch()` before button1 so that it is symmetrical you must set another `addStretch()` after button2

**The buttons events occur twice:** QAbstractButton already calls the update method when you press the button so it is not necessary to connect pressed or released signals to the `update()` method or call it in the `enterEvent()` and `leaveEvent()` methods.

Considering the above the solution is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PicButton(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, pixmap_pressed, id_button, parent=None):
        super(PicButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.pixmap_pressed = pixmap_pressed
        self.id_buton = id_button

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.isDown():
            pix = self.pixmap_pressed
            print("botao pressionado: ", self.id_buton)
        else:
            pix = self.pixmap

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), pix)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(131, 82)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =QtWidgets. QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(800, 450, 800, 450)

    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("background.png")
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(pixmap)
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background, brush)
    window.setPalette(palette)

    button1 = PicButton(QtGui.QPixmap("cancel_up.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("cancel_down.png"), "cancel")
    button2 = PicButton(QtGui.QPixmap("ok_up.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("ok_down.png"), "ok")

    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(window)
    layout.addStretch()
    layout.addWidget(button1)
    layout.addWidget(button2)
    layout.addStretch()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```